# Uploading a Build to IOS App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I read through:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH38-SW1

But I am still having an issue with:

1. Creating My IOS Application Build
2. Uploading the Build to ItunesConnect

I understand how to upload the build using Xcode or Application Loader, but I am not exactly sure how to create the IOS Application Build.

I am probably missing something simple. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Presanity Checks:

- Make sure that you have built to an IOS Device
- Xcode > Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Build (Make sure Archive is checked)

Step 1:

Xcode > Product > Archive

Step 2:

Xcode > Window > Organizer

Step 3:

Look for and Click "Upload to App Store" Button in the Organizer

- If the "Upload" or "Validate" buttons are disabled, it means that you are trying to build a generic archive.
- Please check out this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html

Comment: Answers to iOS deployment questions are the kinds of things that leave me with more questions. What does it mean to build to an iOS device? What is a generic archive and how do I not make one?

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure that you have:

1. Signed into the correct Apple ID (Paid Apple Developer Account) under Xcode > Preferences
2. Make sure that you built the application using the paid provisioning profile and certificate for the appropriate Apple ID